# Android ICS widgets - listviews goes blank randomly (when launcher restarts?) RemoteviesService bug?

Tags: android, listview, widget, android-launcher

I've widget with listview inside and few times per day the listview items just disappears. I find out that it can be due to launcher restart - so I tried a little test. I manually restarted launcher, and it just confirmed my suspicion - it's definitely because of launcher restart.

How to deal with this? The rest of widget (buttons, listeners, ...) are working, just listview items disappear and I can't even see empty_list layout, that I defined - that's why i must add to my widget manual refresh button, but it's not very good solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok except that it's ICS bug, it's partially also my fault - just always recreate widget content in onUpdate method and it will be ok ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are encounterung seems to be a known issue: see link here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28216

There you can find some workaround on how to fix this.

Comment: I read whole thread, but there are no solutions for this error :(

Comment: It should work if you update your android version. I know, this is not the best solution, especially if your phone can't support it. Strange that android developpers haven't fixed this yet !

Comment: hm it's bug which I noticed in ICS, Jelly Bean 4.1 and also 4.1.2...strange.